# How can using a BackgroundWorker cause a Access-Control-Allow-Origin error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I'm making a AngularJS website that uses a Web API 2.
The API needs to send an email when a new user is created.
This works perfectly when I send the email synchronous. However when I try to send it with a BackgroundWorker it's giving me a 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.' error.

Here is some of the code I'm using:

Controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[RoutePrefix("api/user")]
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]

public class UserController : ApiController
{
[HttpPost]
    [ResponseType(typeof(UserDto))]
    [Route("add")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostPerson([FromBody] UserDto userDto)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        try
        {
            var result = await _repository.PostPerson(userDto);
            if (result == null)
            {
                return Conflict();
            }
            return CreatedAtRoute("Default", new { id = result.Id }, result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Repository:

```
public async Task<UserDto> PostPerson(UserDto userDto)
    {
        try
        {
//Rest of code not shown

            var fullName = userDto.FirstName + " " + userDto.Lastname;
            _mailer.SendAccountCreatedMail(fullName, userDto.Email, pw);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userDto.Image))
            {
                SaveUserImage(userDto.MemberNr, userDto.Image);
            }
            userDto.Id = user.Id;
            return userDto;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (PersonExists(userDto.Email, userDto.MemberNr))
            {
                var userToDelete = _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email.Equals(userDto.Email));
                await _userManager.DeleteAsync(userToDelete);
                throw;
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Mailer:

```
public class Mailer : IMailer
{
    private const string FromAddress = "xxx";


    private static SmtpClient Smtpclient => new SmtpClient()
    {
        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        Port = 587,
        EnableSsl = true,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FromAddress, "xxx")
    };

    public void SendAccountCreatedMail(string fullName, string to, string pw)
    {
        try
        {
            BackgroundWorker emailSender = new BackgroundWorker();
            emailSender.DoWork += delegate
            {
                using (var client = Smtpclient)
                {
                    var bodyString = new StringBuilder();
                    var inline = CreatePxlBanner();
                    bodyString.Append("<html><head></head><body>");
                    bodyString.Append("<h3>Beste " + fullName + "</h3>");
                    bodyString.Append("<div><img style='width: 35%;' src='cid:" + inline.ContentId +
                                      "'/></div></body></html>");
                    var alvernateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(bodyString.ToString(), null,
                        MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
                    alvernateView.LinkedResources.Add(inline);
                    var message = new MailMessage
                    {
                        From = new MailAddress(FromAddress),
                        Sender = new MailAddress(FromAddress),
                        Subject = "xxx",
                        IsBodyHtml = true,
                        AlternateViews = {alvernateView}
                    };
                    message.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
                    client.Send(message);
                }
            };
            emailSender.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

The user is created and even the mail is send, but I'm getting a 500 error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:59063/api/user/add. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:6888' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Can anybody explain to me why using the BackGroundWorker is causing  the ' No Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header' error?